# Equations of Perpendicular Lines that meet at $(2,3,-5)$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

> Give the equations of two lines that meet at the point $(2,-3,5)$ and which meet at right angles, but do not use that point in either of your equations. Explain your reasoning and include a LanGraph of your line.

I would know how to find these lines if I could use the point $(2,-3,5)$, but I have no clue how do do it without using that point. I know I must find two perpendicular lines which both have a solution for that certain point, but that is all I know.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: If your question does pertain to the _Mathematica_ software, please include the code you have written so far.

Comment: This question has an infinity of answers. One the simplest solutions is a line in the $yz$-plane with only $x$ varying and a 2nd line in the $xy$-plane with only $z$ varying. Since these two lines must pass through $(2,3,-5)$ it is clear that are represented by the vector expressions $(x,3,-5)$ and $(2,3,z)$ To show they are perpendicular, form the dot product $(2,3,-5)-(0,3,-5))\cdot((2,3,-5)-(2,3,0))$, which gives 0.

Comment: It says do not use the point the *expresss* either of the lines.  You can use the point to figure out the lines but then express them in terms that don't use the point.